# Как включать jQuery библиотеку на wordpress plugin-е чтобы было правильно?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Я в моём файле написал так

```
wp_enqueue_script('cwp-main-datepicker', plugins_url('/Scripts/jquery.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core'));
```

Но говорят, что это не правильный вариант, надо воспользоваться стандартными библиотеками которые включены в wordpress. Какой jQuery файл мне включать, и как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datepicker уже есть в Wordpress. Вам нужно всего лишь указате его в зависимостях к вашему скрипту

```
wp_enqueue_script('cwp-my-scritp', plugins_url('/Scripts/jquery.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery','jquery-ui-datepicker', 'jquery-ui-core'));
```

или просто подключить его в своей теме

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker')
```

Тут есть полный список библиотек которые включены в ядро:

https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC/wp_enqueue_script